# Resetting a dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows 10) to then install latest version of Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

My starting point was a Windows 10 install. Later I partitioned my hard drive and created a dual boot with Ubuntu.

I now want to move to an Ubuntu only computer set up, so uninstall Windows, get rid of the partitions etc.

What are my options?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to back up all your data and perform a fresh install of Ubuntu on the drive, then copy your data back.

You probably could relatively easily upgrade your current Ubuntu to the latest release, delete the windows partition and then either have that as a data drive in your Ubuntu only system, or (invoking a bit more risk and needing a bit of technical knowledge), extend your Ubuntu partition into the free space created by deleting windows (though that seemingly easy task can be tricky, especially if the new free space is before rather than after your Ubuntu partition).

But I think - given how fast it is to install Ubuntu - it is likely to be quicker and give a cleaner result if you perform a fresh install.

The Ubuntu installer will let you do that easily - it’s self explanatory when you choose to install.

Comment: Brilliant. thanks very much Will